# Store data of a then block into json or txt file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a code block to scrape some information from a url and after receiving the data inside the .then block in node.js I don't know how to store them in .txt file or create a json data out of it.

```js
import { Builder, By, Key, until, promise } from 'selenium-webdriver'
import fs from 'fs'

export async function indeed() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
  const where = "" 
  const what = ""
  const search_phrase = "l=" + where + "&q=" + what
  await driver.get("https://google.com/search?" + search_phrase + "&searchFields=jt")

  var flag = false

  while (flag === false){
    try{
      await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@data-gnav-element-name='SignIn']")), 60000)
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@data-gnav-element-name='SignIn']`)).click()
      flag = true
    }
    catch (err){
      console.log(err)
      flag = false
    }
  }

  flag = false
  while (flag === false){
    try{
      await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('input')), 60000)
      flag = true
    }
    catch (err){
      console.log(err)
      flag = false
    }
  }
  flag = false
  while (flag === false){
    try{
      await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@data-cauto-id='name']")), 3600000)
      var elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-cauto-id='name']"))
      promise.map(elements, e => e.getText())
        .then(function(values) {
        });
      promise.map(elements, e => e.getAttribute("href"))
        .then(function(values) {
        });
      flag = true
    }
    catch (err){
      console.log(err)
      flag = false
    }
  }    
}
```

I prefer to have json data that I want to return it to use in future. but .txt file is also ok. please help

Comment: Why don't you use a database?

Answer (score 0):

The the `fs` module to write to file.
https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/how-to-write-files-in-nodejs/

If you want to save it as JSON,

- Take the values and create an object
- call `JSON.stringify` on that object
- write that object to file using `fs` module

Later to use

- read that file using `fs` module
- take the stringified json and call JSON.parse
- you have the original object to work with

from Node REPL,

```sh
> let testJSON = {first:{second:'things'}}
undefined
> JSON.stringify(testJSON)
'{"first":{"second":"things"}}'
> let stringifedJSON = JSON.stringify(testJSON)
undefined
> stringifedJSON
'{"first":{"second":"things"}}'
> stringifedJSON.split('')
[
  '{', '"', 'f', 'i', 'r', 's',
  't', '"', ':', '{', '"', 's',
  'e', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'd', '"',
  ':', '"', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n',
  'g', 's', '"', '}', '}'
]
> JSON.parse(stringifedJSON)
{ first: { second: 'things' } }
```

Comment: the splitting was to show that the stringified JSON is now a string, which can have string operations performed on it.